# Overlapping Transparency issue when drawing GL_POINTS

Tags: android, opengl-es, blend

I have implemented free hand drawing using cubic curve and GL_POINT.
It's working fine for solid color, now I want to implement neon style drawing below is screenshot of instagram 
[Instgram neon brush](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGS99.png)

According to Instagram neon.

1) If Curve (line) intersect itself transparency don't add.

2) if two different curve overlap then they behave like overlay.

How can i achieve that , I don't want to use offscreen rendering because free hand drawing should be smooth.I'm using android and OpenGLES.
I can't use MAX blending , stencil or depth test because at edge of curve glow alpha vary between 1.0 to 0.0.